# How can I pass an object reference to an inner directive in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which creates an autocomplete input

```
angular.module('autocomplete', [] )
    .directive('autocomplete', function (...) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                "id": "@id",
                "selectedObject": "=selectedobject",
                "baseSearchUrl" : "@basesearchurl"
            },
            templateUrl: "..."
            link: function(...){...}
        }
    }
```

an example of usage:

```
<autocomplete
    id="favoriteMovie"
    selectedobject='favMovie'
    searchUrl='/rest/movies?search=' />
```

It works great. Now what I want is to create a new, more specific, directive that create an autocomplete for movies, so I can use it like this:

```
<autocompleteMovie
    id="favoriteMovie"
    selectedmovie='favMovie'/>
```

The new directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('autocompletemovie', [])
.directive(
    'autocompletemovie',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope : {
                "id" : "@",
                "selectedMovie" : "=selectedmovie"
            },
            templateUrl : '...'
        };
    });
```

My Html template for the new component:

```
<autocomplete
    id="{{id}}"
    selectedobject='{{selectedMovie}}'
    searchUrl='/rest/movies?search=' />
```

But this is not working. The `id` attribute is passed correctly to the "inner" `autocomplete`, however the object reference set by the `selectedmovie` attribute is not working.

I have made a second try, passing the name of the object reference instead of the object itself:

Directive:

```
angular.module('autocompletemovie', [])
.directive(
    'autocompletemovie',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope : {
                "id" : "@",
                "selectedMovie" : "@selectedmovie"
            },
            templateUrl : '...'
        };
    });
```

But that did not work as well.

I hope that you can understand what I'm trying to achieve.

[Edit]
I have also tried :

```
<autocomplete
    id="{{id}}"
    selectedobject='selectedMovie'
    searchUrl='/rest/movies?search=' />
```

But it doesn't work. An object with the fixed name `selectedMovie` is created on the scope, even if I call the directive with a different `selectedmovie` attribute:

```
<autocompleteMovie
    id="favoriteMovie"
    selectedmovie='favMovie'/>
```

In the example above I would like to have an object called `favoriteMovie` and not `selectedMovie`.

[/Edit]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
<autocomplete
    id="{{id}}"
    selectedobject='{{selectedMovie}}'
    searchUrl='/rest/movies?search=' />
```

to

```
<autocomplete
    id="{{id}}"
    selectedobject='selectedMovie'
    searchUrl='/rest/movies?search=' />
```

The = syntax in a directive binds to an object while the {{ }} syntax is going to get interpreted as a string. The id works because @ passes the interpreted string value into the directive.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it doesn't work as I expected. I've edited the question to add further explanation.